# How useful is Lucene/Solr in database search?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new in development and I need your advice.

Our student team is going to develop an application for online restaurant booking, where also will be search tool (restaurant and dishes search).

We want to use modern search tool like Lucene, but we are not sure if it is what we really need.

Due to knowledge information, this is more for text search with different kinds of indexes and so on, while our app will make search in database. BUT, if we want to add new features in future, I guess we need good search engine background today.

So, let me know if Lucene is able to do "select" operations or something like it, or this technology is just for text searches?

Sedond question, what can you advise in realisation of this feature? Where to start with?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends. You usually don't start with Lucene and Solr, you use it to attain a goal or implement a specific behavior you need. Usually Solr is your secondary storage, built from your primary database - i.e. you're inserting data into Solr to solve a specific need, for example proper full text search with relevancy scoring.

If you're just starting up, go with the technology you know - i.e. usually a regular RDBMS. You can then attach Solr if you need those features that they're really good at, and wait with introducing new technology until it's necessary. The need first, then the technology. Maybe Lucene/Solr isn't the right technology for what you end up needing when you get to that point.

One of the main tenants of modern development is "YAGNI" - You Ain't Gonna Need It. You implement features when you need them, not for some imagined behavior that may or may not show up down the road.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But, we just want to use technologies in our project too. So, if it is possible to use Lucene as query select tool, we want to try it. 

So, does Lucene can be used as qurey select tool? (if I form question correctly)

Comment: Sure. You can query based on specific values in specific fields on documents. But remember that Lucene is a document oriented engine - it's not a 1:1 mapping to what relational databases do. In general you want to structure all information about an item in a single (usually flat) document, then query the index to find documents that match that query. For the search feature you describe above (restaurants and dishes), it'll be a very good match. It'll also give you a feature that you've probably seen many places, namely "Facets". These allow you to quickly implement "Filter by .." navigators